# Is it possible to update a field of type map in firestore from firebase cloud functions node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I do this in my node.js in firebase cloud functions:

```
 var my_map = new Map();
 my_map.set('name','foo');
 my_map.set('description','helloworld');

 //update the firestore document
 let updateDocument = documentRef.update({ 
                some_field: my_map
                });
```

I get the following error in the logs:

> failed to query incidents Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object (found in field "some_field").

I have checked the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data but the only map-related example given seems to deal with updating nested fields. I want to create a map and easily set a field in a firestore document to the contents of this map.

I am new to both node.js and firestore. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Firestore SDK for node doesn't support ES6 Map objects.  You need to use a normal JavaScript object to build a Firestore map type field.

```
const o = {
    name: 'foo',
    description 'helloworld'
}

documentRef.update({
    some_field: o
});
```

Comment: Hi @Doug. What if my field name is derived programmatically? In above example, what if my some_field is going to contain a username which can be any string. How can I do that. Right now, the variable name is being treated as the field name.

Comment: @AbhijeetKharatmol You could post a new question here on Stack Overflow to describe in more detail what you're trying to do, along with your code.

Answer (score 3):

As Doug Steven said, it doesn't support map, you can convert your map to plain JS object by:

`const updateObj = Object.fromEntries(yourMap);`

then pass it to update

`documentRef.update(updateObj);`